# How to change font in Android Studio 2.2 rc from bold to normal

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio 2.2rc and in this version default code style looks bolder then in (for example) 2.1. Can I return normal font style and use 2.2rc at the same time?
(You can see the difference in font on this pictures, but settings are the same)

[2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q2Ly.png)

[2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvTiM.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to IDEA settings, find Appearance -> Antialiasing, and set Editor or IDE to Grayscale.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.